# merge two pages with different styles into one

Tags: html, css, django, merge

I want to include a webpage into another, but preferably without an iframe, since I hate the scrollbars in the middle of the page.

Lets say I want to include A as a part of B

I tried doing it by creating a div on B where I wanted to include A then loading the page using JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#inv_view').html('loading...').load("{% url 'invoice.invoice.view' invoice.ID %}");
});
```

My problem is that A uses its own set of CSS styles and these override the styles on B when A is loaded. How can i prevent this?

Again, I know it is easily done with an iframe, but... Meh

Comment: Is page B a full page, with a `<head>` section and all that? If so, this won't work so well. But if page B is just a snippet of code, a PHP include would be good for this.

Comment: With JavaScript loading you might probably not have the CSS of the page B loaded at all. Check in a Network register in Firebug for Firefox or similar tool, if the CSS is loaded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy to do this, unless you control both pages stylesheets.

If you do, just prepend all the of rules with a class selector.

Place this class on the body tag within each template.

When you pull one page into the other, just wrap it in a div with your class.

Comment: sounds like a straightforward idea. Don't know why I didn't think of it. Simply wrap all the styles of A in a class and use that :) Thanks buddy

Answer (score -1):

**You can do this very easily through PHP.  Here are the steps you need to take:**

1: Change your two files from `.html` to `.php` ( this will allow php to be read )

2: In fileB where you want to include the content from fileA, write the following:

```
        <?php include 'fileA.php' ?>
```

3: In your fileA, delete the `<html>`, `<header>`, and `<body>` tags.  Just keep the content that you want to transfer over to fileB.

---

To avoid the CSS changes from taking place, you will need to add `id`'s where there are overlapping conflicts. **Another option:** you can also put all of fileA inside a div. Then, where styles overlap access the div directly like this example:

```
p {
    font-size:18px;
}
#fileA p {
    font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from my description of the problem, but I am using Django with python, so PHP is not preferable :)

Comment: Gotcha. I missed the django tag.  Sorry about that. =)